# Split first child node from the rest using XSLT

Tags: xslt, split, nodes

Can anyone help me to split the child nodes using XSLT. Only `child1` should be split from rest of the children.

```
<parent>
    <child1>
    <child2>
    <child3>
<parent>
```

output:

```
<parent>
    <child1>
    <element>
         <child2>
         <child3>
    </element>
<parent>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="data.xsl"?>
<data>
    <parent>
        <child>123</child>
        <child>345</child>
        <child>678</child>
    </parent>
</data>
```

And want to show it like this:

```
<span>123</span>
<ul>
   <li>345</li>
   <li>678</li>
</ul>
```

If it is right, use next code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="parent">
        <strong><xsl:value-of select="child[1]/text()"/></strong>
        <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="child">
            <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
                <li><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></li>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is there any way where I can genrate the below output

Comment: Sorry, not undestand question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432820/add-sub-child-of-a-child-to-a-element I posted the Question int this link.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <parent>
      <xsl:copy-of select="child1"/>
      <element>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::child1)]"/>
      </element>
    </parent>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the provided XML:**

```
<parent>
  <child1/>
  <child2/>
  <child3/>
</parent>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<parent>
  <child1/>
  <element>
    <child2/>
    <child3/>
  </element>
</parent>
```

Comment: I suspect `child1` actually has the same name as `child2`, `child3` etc. and needs to be distinguished as `parent/*[1]`

Comment: @Borodin - I hope you aren't assuming that the above comment was from me. As for your original comment, that is a fair assumption; however, given that no additional context was given for this question, I have answered this question fully and produced the requested output. If something else was required, the OP should have provided that information in *this* question and not forced the community to make broad assumptions.

Comment: @ABach: Indeed I hadn't noticed that the comment wasn't from you. I apologize and I have removed the comment.

Comment: @Borodin - no problem at all. :)